# Need help in Active Record Associations in Rails with self referential and many to one mapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, polymorphic-associations

**Requirement:** 

I'm creating a twitter like web application for the local campus where users can share their feedback over a service within 140 characters just like the way twitter does.

For every feedback , there can be multiple responses to the feedback. These responses are similar to twitter replies , where replies are also 140 character response like a tweet.

Essentially the screen for entering a feedback or a response is the same with the same functional elements.
 Example would be :-

> This is a demo feedback - user 1 
>       This is a response to the feedback - user 2

---

I'm using rails for the development and this is what my feedback model looks like

```
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title     

end
```

My table structure in the database looks like this:-
**Feedback Table**

> id , integer , primary key 
> title, varchar (255)

This is how I want to manage responses to a feedback

A separate table named "**Feedback_Responses**" with the following structure :

> feedback_id (int) [This is a parent feedback id] 
>  response_id
>   (int) [This is a response to the parent feedback id]

**My Question**
I understand that self referential mapping is needed over here with many to one relationship. However, I'm not clear as to how to proceed with creation of a response from the same **view** that is used to create a **feedback**. And secondly, a response is another feedback to the system so unless a response is created and its id is generated , the Feedback_Responses table wont be populated with the required mapping. So, in this case I'm really clueless and perhaps confused as to how to create responses and manage their mappings on a separate table. I'm starting to learn rails with this application.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title 
  validates :title, :length => { :maximum => 140 }
  has_many_and_belong_to :responses   
end

class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many_and_belong_to :feedbacks      
end
```

To fetch responses from a feedback object use `@feedback.responses`
same for the response object `@response.feedbacks` 
This relation is easy to maintain. You can add middle table if you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding your design very well, but it looks like your main entity (equivalent to a tweet) is the "feedback" and each "feedback" can have many "responses" (like comments). What is not clear to me is whether the "response" can be a "feedback" in its own right, but I'm going to assume it's not, for now. So, your design says, according to this description, that a feedback has many responses. I find that "feedback_responses" table irrelevant for the matter, because it sounds like a response is connected to one and only one feedback. So, drop the table.

So, I would write it like this:

```
# table feedbacks
# id: Integer
# title: Varchar 140
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :responses
end

# table responses
# id: Integer
# feedback_id: Integer
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :feedback
end
```

Still, if you want to handle the response has a feedback which is not a response to another feedback, you can just use inheritance as a solution:

```
# additionally feedback_id: Integer to the feebacks table
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :responses
end

class Response < Feedback
  belongs_to :feedback
end
```

View generation will be automatically easy as long as you have two distinguishable models.